# First Row in Data Table Does not "Format as Table"

Tags: excel, formatting

I have some data tables in Excel 2013 that aren't formatting the first row of data properly.  While I do have some conditional formatting, the one that formats cells white/blank is for blank values and by nature *can't* be the cause of what I am showing.

Here are some samples of table formatting not working, and my conditional rule for blank values which doesn't even include the columns in question

[image]

I am at a loss, I have no idea why the first data row of these columns won't format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am tired, and was overlooking the simple stuff. Even though I had the tables conditionally formatted AND formatted as a table, I also had a "Cell Style" set for those handful of cells, that seemed to override all my formatting.